# changing the contents of a dll

Tags: c, dll

This is for a homework assignment.

I am supposed to change the contents of a dll function and put an error in it (0xCC). After loading the dll function and changing its protection to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.

I am having a trouble planting the error code in it. I tried the following (I removed the non interesting things):

```
typedef BOOL (*pfn)();

HMODULE hModule=LoadLibrary("somedll");

pfn somefunc=(pfn)GetProcAddress(hModule,"somefunction");

VirtualProtect (somefunc,dwSize,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&dwOldProtect);

BYTE *p = (BYTE*)somefunc;

*p = 0xCC;
```

When I execute `somefunc`, instead of getting an exception, it is running without any problems. Why is that and am I doing wrong?

How do I overwrite the function?

Comment: Are you running `somefunc` in the same process?

Comment: a. yes i am running somefunc in  the same process.

b. this is what i am asking - how do i overwrite the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably VirtualProtect returned an error. Check its (BOOL) return value and, if false, use GetLastError to check what was the cause.

Notice that VirtualProtect must be compatible with the access given at the call to VirtualAlloc that allocated the memory. Now, that's something you can't control, since VirtualAlloc is called internally in LoadLibrary.

Another thing is that the pointer provided to VirtualProtect must be the starting address to that memory page, and the function pointer you provided most probably is not. Your function can be anywhere inside the page, you'll have to adjust it to the nearest page start before.

Of interest:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127904
(basically what you're doing, but a few more steps required)

http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/
(may be helpful for details on DLL loading mechanism)

Comment: i did check the bool value - and no error there. If i provide the function's pointer - does that not mean that i can write into it? (i tried to change the protection to read - and indeed got access exception) i am trying to change the function itself - and no matter how many bytes i change there - it is still executed without any exceptions...

Comment: Well, if VirtualProtect succeeds, then possibly the only thing you need is to call FlushInstructionCache() before calling the function pointer.

Comment: Also notice that MS recommend doing this in two steps: first change the access mode to PAGE_WRITECOPY only, then modify the code, and then modify the access mode to PAGE_EXECUTE again. Don't know if this makes any difference, but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the function runs successfully? Can you run your code in debugger (OllyDbg, for example) and make sure that:

1. You code writes 0xCC at certain address,
2. 0xCC was written successfully,
3. And there is no exception on the 0xCC opcode.

Comment: I've written a simple dll that contains a function that prints out to the screen some output. The function is executed - and this is not what i want to happen...

Comment: Could you change 0xCC to 0xF4 (HLT) to see is there any difference?

Comment: i changed it and there is no difference. thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I don't know where is the problem. I wrote similar code and it works fine for me (in OllyDBG) - take a look on that: [link](http://pastebin.com/5tHHFnTR)